# Can I remove form Inspector from generated PDF in Orbeon?

Tags: pdf, orbeon, inspector

is it possible to ommit Form Inspector from generated PDF in Orbeon? Thank you.

Comment: The XForms Inspector shouldn't show in PDFs. But maybe you have the `oxf.epilogue.xforms.inspector` property set to `true`? If so, you can just set it to `false`. (You only want to set it to `true` momentarily, when debugging something with the XForms Inspector.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @avernet. You're right, I have it turned on for debugging purposes. But since I am in a transitional period on my project I need it to have turned on for debugging but at the same time I would like not to have in PDF output. Is there a way? Like ex. enable Inspector only in edit mode (which would be enough for me)?

Comment: Got it LJ, I've posted some suggestions in an answer below, even if it looks to me like the configuration you're looking for doesn't exactly exist in Orbeon Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no configuration that you can set to have the XForms Inspector enabled only on certain pages. If you enable the XForms Inspector by setting the `oxf.epilogue.xforms.inspector` property to `true`, then it will show everywhere. So you can either:

1. Enable it very temporary, setting the property to `true` just before doing a page load for which you want it, and then set it to `false` (or commenting out the property).
2. Add custom CSS that hides the XForms Inspector when needed. In this case, the XForms Inspector will still be "there", but just hidden with CSS. And of course, you'll want to make sure to really disable it before going to production.

Comment: Thank you @avernet, I'll go with the CSS route.

Comment: Got it @LJ, thanks for the update, and you'll just let me know know in case using CSS for this is causing you any trouble.